# How do I access remote push notification data on applicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications

When receiving a remote push notification as the application is in the background, the app enters applicationDidBecomeActive. From there, how can I access the NSDictionary of data from the notification?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The notification data is delivered to your app in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. If you want to process it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` you should store it in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and read it again in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: Sorry to revive this, but what happens when you receive the notification on application:didReceiveRemoteNotification and your application is in the foreground, which means applicationDidBecomeActive will not be called.

Comment: In `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` you can query `-[UIApplication applicationState]` to find out if your app is already in the foreground. If it is then just process the notification right away.

Answer (score 2):

Swift version:

```
var dUserInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

// code...

if let info = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
        dUserInfo = info
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    dUserInfo = userInfo
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // code...

    self.yourAction(dUserInfo)
}

func yourAction(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    if let info = userInfo?["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to manage the push:

In the AppDelegate

```
@implementation AppDelegate{
    NSDictionary *dUserInfo; //To storage the push data
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Check for options
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        //Store the data from the push.
        dUserInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dUserInfo != nil)
        {
            //Do whatever you need
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    //Data from the push.
    if (dUserInfo != nil)
    {
        //Do whatever you need
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //Store the data from the push.
    if (userInfo != nil)
    {
        dUserInfo = userInfo;
    }
}
```

I hope this will be useful for someone.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in `background` state when push notification is received and tapped, the app will get invoked with `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and not `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.

Push notification payload can be accessed in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` from `launchOptions` dictionary.

Comment: This is not correct application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is not called when the app is in background, this is only called when the application starts. what you are saying is totally  oposite, first it will be called application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: and then applicationDidBecomeActive: